# Minimize windows Excel application programmatically using C#

Tags: c#, excel, windows

I have a windows service that is responsible for minimizing a specific Excel document that is opened in windows on start up.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: If your windows service opens the file via Excel automation, then still via the latter, loop on each Workbook, get each Window and set its windowstate to minimized. `foreach (Excel.Workbook item in oExcelApp.Workbooks)
{
  item.Windows[1].WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlMinimized;
}`

Comment: A Windows service normally can't show any UI or interact with the desktop. It runs in the background before any user has logged in. If you want to open a file when a user logs in, then a scheduled task is probably a better choice.